# Book - Title mentions a falcon or peregrine, cloak on the cover, includes menstruation as a teen problem

Tags: story-identification, novel

I've been trying to find a book for someone - she read it as a kid (between 1993-1997) and can't remember much about it.

The bits that are remembered have to do with, or the title is something about a falcon, or peregrine (which makes googling impossible - every result shows "Miss Peregrine") There's someone in a dark cloak on the cover. And the hero is a teenage girl who deals with real issues in the book, like menstruating - which is why she remembers the character. As a teen, it was cool the main character dealt with real issues.

And that's literally all I have to go off of. Needless to say I've hit a ton of dead ends. Sound even remotely familiar to anyone?

So far I've dug up these ones which don't completely match:

- *Sabriel*
- *Throne of Glass*
- *Golden Compass*

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Thank you for those who are helping to edit my post, I appreciate the help!

Comment: When was your friend a kid, so that we can try to pin down a timeframe? And can you run that guide by your friend and see if she can answer any of those questions?

Comment: 1993-1997 was the time frame I have for when she would have read it! Could have been a newer book for the time or an older one!

Comment: Lloyd Alexander had a series about Westmark.  The second book title is [The Kestrel](https://www.amazon.com/Kestrel-Westmark-Trilogy-Lloyd-Alexander/dp/0141310693/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1502308906&sr=1-1&keywords=the+kestrel).

Comment: What about this book was science fictional or fantasy?

Comment: @SteveMyer - if you come back, take a look at this post:https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227843/fantasy-story-with-a-young-female-protagonist-and-an-ageless-wizard?rq=1, the main character is a teenage girl, the accepted answer mentions that it describes her getting her fist period.

Comment: @SteveMyer - again, if you come back, this could also have your answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227870/fantasy-magic-book-with-female-protagonist-and-a-misogynistic-villain-in-a-ringe?r

Answer (score 4):

This one is a long shot, but maybe *Hawkmistress* by Marion Zimmer Bradley?

The main protagonist is a girl struggling with the limited traditional role for women in her world.  She runs away and works as a bird keeper for sentry birds.  She had trained her own hawk before she ran away (this precipitated the crisis).

She does have to deal with menstruation as an issue (in one scene she uses it to delay being forcibly married, so she can run away.  In another place it comes up because she has to deal with it while on the trail, disguised as a boy.  Not primarily as a "teen problem", as you mentioned).

I don't know if there was an edition with someone in a dark cloak on the cover; the cover I recognize has her with her trained falcon.  Cloaks were worn; it is a  cold planet.  So there might have been such a cover; not sure.  Other books in the series probably had people in cloaks on the cover, though I don't remember offhand.

Comment: *Hawkmistress* was the first thing that popped into my head when I was reading the original post. If you hadn't suggested it, I would have.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still interested here It could be the [Path of Fate](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13920.Path_of_Fate) by Diana Pharaoh Francis. It’s one in a [trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40477-path)!

It doesn’t have falcon in the title but there is one on the cover with the girl in the dark green cloak and she has a pet falcon (sorta) in the story.

[image]

Comment: Is menstruation part of the narrative?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'm mostly through the first book of the trilogy.  While Reisil starts the story as a _tark_ (healer) neither she nor any patients deal with menstruation.  Reading summaries of the other books, it seems unlikely that she'd end up dealing with that particular issue, but I'll read on.