# Book series about a girl and her hawk/falcon companion she can speak to going on a quest

Tags: story-identification, books

I vaguely recall the plot of a series that I'm looking for. A girl is sent on a quest. She has a hawk/falcon and she can speak to it. They are both shown on every book cover. Each book cover has a white background, with gold leaves/filigree around the outside.

The books might be from the early 2000s. I read these books in middle school, I believe, and they form a trilogy.

Comment: Kiesha'ra series by Amelia Atwater-Rhodes seems familiar. The heir to the Avian throne, Danica Shardae wants peace between her people and their foes the serpiente . Her quest was to make it possible. The hawk was more like her second form, they were all shapeshifters. The girl and the hawk are featured on the first book cover but nothing else matches. There are 5 books, not three. It was published in 2003.

Comment: I checked this series out, but it isn’t the one I’m looking for. This looks intriguing though.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking back through some of the questions I'd saved as favorites and saw [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/181197/78394).  Looking into the trilogy it mentions, I think it is what you're looking for.

The [*Path*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40477-path) trilogy by Diana Pharaoh Francis (2003-2006).  The books are

1. [*Path of Fate*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13920.Path_of_Fate)
2. [*Path of Honor*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6986544-path-of-honor)
3. [*Path of Blood*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13921.Path_of_Blood)

The Goodreads blurb on the first book:

> *In the land of Kodu Riik, becoming  ahalad-kaaslane  is the highest honor one can achieve. It mans the Lady has chosen you to bond and be united forever with one of Her specially blessed animals -- soul to soul...*
>
> Abandoned by her parents as an infant, Reisil grew up perpetually reminded that she did not belong. There wasn't a moment when she didn't feel like apologizing just for existing -- until she became a tark and proudly discovered her talent for healing.
>
> Now, when Reisil believes she has finally found the security and sense of belonging she has always craved, she is chosen by the Blessed Lady to be  ahalad-kaaslane  --one of the judges, soldiers, spies, and explorers who travel the land, bound to no one but the Lady Herself. Devastated by the thought of losing her hard-won place in the world, Reisil rejects the Lady's gift and the  ahalad-kaaslane  goshawk who needs her.
>
> But Reisil's decision does not affect her alone. Soon the fate of all Kodu Riik will rest in her hands --- and Reisil will be forced to make a bitter choice to save her people from the horrors of war....

Covers from Goodreads:

[image: Path of Fate cover] [image: Path of Honor cover] [image: Path of Blood cover]
<sub>*Click to embiggen.*</sub>

One of the Goodreads [reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/117459952?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1) is more explicit about the telepathic goshawk:

> Saljane is one of the best-realized telepathic companion animals I've encountered - she provides love and support and all that wonderfulness, but she is a *bird* and she acts like a *bird*, always, not only when it would be cute or plot-convenient or funny.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [*Flight of the Dragon Kyn*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/409717) (1993) By Susan Fletcher? It's part of "*The Dragon Chronicles*" series of books.

> This is a story about Kara and dragons. When she was four, she came
> down with vermillion fever. Her parents, thinking there was no cure,
> left her in a cave to die. A month later she walked back into her
> parents' home as healthy as if she had never been sick. It is said
> that a mother dragon lived in that cave, and she nursed young Kara
> back to life. Now, eleven years later, the only reminder of Kara's
> illness is a small scar on her cheek. Of her contact with the dragon,
> there is more. Her eyes, which once were blue, are now green. And she
> can call down birds, which many believe is a sign that she can also
> call down dragons, for the two are distant cousins.
>
> Only Kara has her doubts. How can a beast as huge and terrifying as a
> dragon be related to a sweet, gentle bird? But could this explain why
> the king has sent for her? Does he think she has power over dragons?
> For Kara, the answer to this question means life or death - not only
> for her, but for all the dragons, also.
>
> [image]

Comment: I've found an edition of the book with a white cover with yellow surround. The others in the series had a [similar](https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/fa5b1722284049.5630fba53838b.jpg) [theming](https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/82c03722284049.5630fba5224ae.jpg)

Comment: And if this the correct book series, OP will be pleased to learn that [a fourth book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7171859-ancient-strange-and-lovely) was published in 2010, making this a quadrilogy, not a trilogy.